# NVIDIA/DIGITS Run Time Error?

Tags: nvidia, numpy

I have installed DIGITS on Ubuntu 16.04 regarding the NVIDIA/DIGITS. When I run `./digits-devserver`
output becomes:

> RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa
>   RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals
>     File "/home/deep/digits/digits/**main**.py", line 70, in 
>       main()
>     File "/home/deep/digits/digits/**main**.py", line 53, in main
>       import digits.config
>     File "digits/config/**init**.py", line 7, in 
>       from . import (  # noqa
>     File "digits/config/tensorflow.py", line 16, in 
>       tf_enabled = test_tf_import()
>     File "digits/config/tensorflow.py", line 11, in test_tf_import
>       import tensorflow  # noqa
>     File "/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
>     File "/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 52, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
>     File "/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
>     File "/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
>     File "/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
>     File "/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
>     File "/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle_pb2.py", line 41, in 
>       options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
>   TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'

For 1 week, I am trying to install and solve problems by googling. I just want to use DIGITS anymore. I hope this is my last problem and I will solve with your helps.

Thanks in advance, Ender.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling right packages. For Nvidia/Digits, install cuda-9.0 (it includes nvidia driver 384.111), cuDNN 7.1 and caffe 0.15. Everything is okay.